# Dealing with scan error in R - Caused by misplaced \n separators in data

Tags: r, read.table

I'm reading in many large tab-separated `.txt` files using `read.table` in R. However, some lines contain newline breaks (`\n`) where there should be tabs (`\t`), which causes an `Error in scan(...)`. How can I deal with this issue robustly? (Is there a way to replace `\n`-->`\t` every time `scan` encounters an error?)

Edit:

Here's a simple example:

```
read.table(text='a1\tb1\tc1\td1\n
                 a2\tb2\tc2\td2', sep='\t')
```

works fine, and returns a data frame. However, suppose there is, by some mistake, a newline `\n` where there should be a tab `\t` (e.g., after `c1`):

```
read.table(text='a1\tb1\tc1\nd1\n
                 a2\tb2\tc2\td2', sep='\t')
```

This raises an error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
    line 1 did not have 4 elements
```

Note: Using `fill=T` won't help, because it will push `d1` to a new row.

Comment: Look at the documentation for scan (`?scan`) - I think that adding the argument `fill=TRUE` should help: "logical: if `TRUE`, scan will implicitly add empty fields to any lines with fewer fields than implied by `what`."

Comment: @Marcinthebox  From what I understand, that's used to deal with missing data... using `fill=T` in my case would split the data into separate rows, which is not what I want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example can you provide a relevant file snippet

Comment: is your question answered? if not try to specifiy what's' missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### if you do have the exact problem you describe (no missing data, just wrong seperator) try:

```
library(readr)
initial_lines <- read_lines('a1\tb1\tc1\nd1\na2\tb2\tc2\td2')

seperated_together <- unlist(strsplit(initial_lines, "\t", fixed = T))

matrix(seperated_together, ncol = 4)
```

gives:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a1" "c1" "a2" "c2"
[2,] "b1" "d1" "b2" "d2"
```

and transform this as you wish wish.

#### if you have missing data/complications then you'll have to:

```
strsplit(initial_lines,'\t',fixed=T)
```

which gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a1" "b1" "c1"

[[2]]
[1] "d1"

[[3]]
[1] "a2" "b2" "c2" "d2"
```

and you'll have to parse through elements combining based on number of elements.

You could also have a look at `?count_fields` in `readr`.